# How to use argv with Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I'm running the code below in Spyder.
I have typed it in a py file and simply hit the run button.

When I try to run it I get the error:

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

As shown here you are meant to give the inputs for the argv variable before running the  program but I don't know how to do this is spyder?

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex13.html

```
from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "The first variable is:", first
print "The second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

Comment: print out `argv`, looks like it is a scalar and not a tuple. What are your command line arguments when calling the script? Did you run `python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd`? Make sure your supply args.

Answer (score -16, accepted):

Read the FAQ at the bottom of the page, it specifically mentions this error.

> ### Common Student Questions
>
> **Q.** When I run it I get `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`.
>
> Remember that an important skill is paying attention to details. If you look at the What You Should See section you see that I run the script with parameters on the command line. You should replicate how I ran it exactly.

Make sure you run the command:

> ```
> $ python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
> ```

> ```
> >> The script is called: ex13.py  
> >> Your first variable is: first  
> >> Your second variable is: 2nd  
> >> Your third variable is: 3rd
> ```

You can ensure that the arguments are supplied.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(argv) == 4:
        script, first, second, third = argv

        print 'The script is called:', script
        print 'Your first variable is:', first
        print 'Your second variable is:', second
        print 'Your third variable is:', third
    else:
        print 'You forgot the args...'
```

Comment: But where do I enter this in console? That doesn't seem to work either? I enter in console: 

    $ python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
and I get the error:
$ python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    $ python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To be clear should I add $ python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd to the scipt or run it in console prior to running the script. Right now neither way seems to work.

Comment: You call the script in the shell/terminal/bash. This example deals with command-line arguments, not the Idle. Open a terminal and run "`python ex13.py first 2nd 3rd`"

Comment: OK I hope this isn't too stupid a question but how do I do that?

Comment: Using [Mac](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYK7NY0BsaA) and [Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x2qtLrQdqU) but this is the most helpful in your situation, watch this: [Youtube: Command Line Arguments in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3uv23jvp4w)

Comment: I think you are confusing @Bazman He asked about how to pass `argv` to a script ran inside Spyder. That's different from running it in a regular terminal. I'll add a proper answer below.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl has answered a different question here. The OP is specifically asking how to use command line arguments from within the Spyder IDE. See Carlos' answer below.

Comment: This answer is completely different from what is being asked!

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 82):

To pass `argv` to a script in Spyder, you need to go the menu entry

`Run > Configuration per file`

or press the <kbd>Ctrl+F6</kbd> key, then look for the option called

`Command line options`

on the dialog that appears after that, and finally enter the command line arguments you want to pass to the script, which in this case could be

`one two three`

Comment: @FTilmann, please take a closer look at the dates. My answer was given on Nov/2014, while Trickster answer was given just a bit more than a month ago.

Comment: I do apologise. I misread the day (13) as the year. Will try to be more careful next time - I deleted my comment as it was clearly inappropriate and based on a stupid mistake of mine.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba

I know this thread is old but is there a faster way to do this now or does one still have to go through Ctrl+F6? 
Thanks

Comment: This has not changed in Spyder 4, sorry.

Answer (score 42):

In addition to configuring in the `Run->Configure` as explained in other answers,
you can use "runfile" directly from the console.

Run the following:

```
   runfile('ex13.py', args='first second third')
```

Answer (score 21):

In Spyder, go `Run > Configure` and define your argv values as showing in following diagram and to run the script just press `F6`

[image: diagram]

Comment: Current Spyder versions (I'm looking at 5.5.1) do not allow setting command line options in this screen unless you choose 'Execute in an external system terminal'.

Comment: P.s. - in Spyder v5.5.1 I see this has been moved further down the "Run configuration per file" dialog. You have to first select "Run file with custom configuration," and then scroll down further to get to the new location for "General Settings" > "Command line options"