# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1) in sypder

Tags: anaconda, python-3.5, spyder

```
 from sys import argv

 script, first, second, third = argv

 print('The script is called'), 'script'
 print('The first varrible is'), 'first'
 print('The second varrible is'), 'second'
 print('The Third Varrible is'), 'third'
```

It keeps prompting This Value Error in Spyder

Comment: What does `print(argv)` return?

Comment: Nothing at all.

Comment: That's what the problem is. `script, first, second, third = argv` requires `argv` to have four elements. What are you trying to do? What should the values be?

Comment: To use `sys.argv` in Spyder, please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679272/not-sure-how-to-use-argv-with-spyder

Comment: #Try This One : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43559167/7502072
#I Think It Will Help You

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I came across this problem at first as well.
I used Command to run the code from Notepad+.

C:\Users\kxyde>Desktop\Python\ex13.py
This command is wrong, since you need three values, you have to type in three after "ex13.py" (Shown below is the right one) :

C:\Users\kxyde>Desktop\Python\ex13.py first 2nd 3rd

Then, problem solved!!

Answer (score -1):

## Solution 1

You could also decide to add the other three arguments in command prompt when trying to view the output, 
as shown here ---> [How to add the three other arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzwyu.jpg)

## Note

Do remember that

"c:\Users\Empress\Desktop\mystuff\ex3.py"

is where the location of my python file is and it had to be entered inorder to get the output of my editied code in the python file.

Hope that helps.