# Error in Argparse python 3.6

Tags: python, argparse

Here the code I'm using; I run it with Python 3.6 in Anaconda:

```
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours

import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True, 
  help = 'path to the input image')
args = vars(ap.parse_args())]
```

and I get an error of:

```
runfile('/Users/suryavamsi/untitled5.py', wdir='/Users/suryavamsi')
usage: untitled5.py [-h] -1 IMAGE
untitled5.py: error: the following arguments are required: -1/--image
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2

/Users/suryavamsi/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2870: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

Comment: Is it '-i' or '-1'?  Your parser definition requires a flagged argument.

Comment: What editor is this in, are you using Spyder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running a command-line script *in your IDE*, with the `runfile()` command and no command-line arguments.

`argparse` is working correctly. A required argument is missing (because `sys.argv` is not set when using `runfile()`), and so raises the [`SystemExit` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) with the correct error code to exit the command-line script.

You appear to be using Spyder, in which case you'd have to set the command-line options with the `Run > Configuration per file` option and add your command line options to the `Command line options` box. See [Not sure how to use argv with Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679272/not-sure-how-to-use-argv-with-spyder).