# How to parse arguments in python (spyder)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, spyder, argparse

I am following [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/04/16/keras-and-convolutional-neural-networks-cnns/) tutorial and trying to run the below part of the script. I am using python 3.7 and spyder 3.3.4.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
    help="path to input dataset (i.e., directory of images)")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model", required=True,
    help="path to output model")
ap.add_argument("-l", "--labelbin", required=True,
    help="path to output label binarizer")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
    help="path to output accuracy/loss plot")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I have tried going to Run > Configuration per file and entering the arguments as advised by [this post and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679272/how-to-use-argv-with-spyder) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53768365/how-to-execute-with-optional-argument-in-spyder).

> command line options: *path1*, *path2*, *path3*, *path4*

I filled out the appropriate paths for the arguments above and then ran the script, but go the error below.

> usage: train.py [-h] -d DATASET -m MODEL -l LABELBIN [-p PLOT]
>   train.py: error: the following arguments are required: -d/--dataset,
>   -m/--model, -l/--labelbin An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback. 
>   SystemExit: 2

How can I fix this error to run my script appropriately and pass the arguments in spyder?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I have the same question.

Comment: Follow the usage message.  In a bash shell the commandline should appear as: `train.py -d path1 -m path2 -l paht3 -p path4'.  Adjust your configuration line accordingly.

Comment: Simply introduce the arguments as you would do it in a system terminal. In other words, instead of passing to Spyder `path1, path2, path3, path4`, please do it as `-d path1 -m path2 -l paht3 -p path4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse arguments by doing a special run from the settings and putting in the order that the arguments are expected.