# How to run my Python code using Spyder, without the error "the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor"?

Tags: python

How can I run this?

```
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=str, default="",
    help="path alarm .WAV file")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
    help="index of webcam on system")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

While I run this on Spyder it gives

```
   usage: [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-a ALARM] [-w WEBCAM]
: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you passing any arguments in when you run it?

Comment: in spyder ctrl+F6 should allow you to pass command-line args when you execute your script. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766414/4954037

Answer (score 0):

From @hiroprotagonist's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970283/how-to-run-my-python-code-using-spyder-without-the-error-the-following-argumen/74166395#comment113119478_63970283) posted above:

> In spyder ctrl+F6 should allow you to pass command-line args when you execute your script. see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766414/4954037.

Comment: If you are going to post someone else's comment as your own answer, please make sure to cite and link to that original comment.